# Controlling the Animation of a zipped PNG Sequence in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to build a player that plays png sequences stored in a zip and I want to be able to control the playback.

For example, all of my zips will have 90 pngs, when the player loads, I want the animation to pause at image 45. When the user swipes right the player should play a few pngs creating the illusion of "fast-forwarding"

The code below plays the png sequence however, I can seem to control anything. I can't even get the animation to start on image 45.

How can I get kivy to load the image sequence from the middle of the sequence, control the play forward and the play in reverse?

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
Window.size = (440, 760)

kv = '''

#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
MDScreen:
    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Image:
            id: display_image
            source: 'video/sophia.zip'
            anim_delay: 1/30
            anim_reset: True
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 480
'''


class PNGPlayer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__== '__main__':
    PNGPlayer().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the animation using the `anim_delay` property of the `Image`. Setting it to `-1` will stop the animation, and setting it to `1/30` will restart it at the same rate as before. Here is a modified version of your code that demonstrates that:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
Window.size = (440, 760)

kv = '''

#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
MDScreen:
    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Image:
            id: display_image
            source: 'video/sophia.zip'
            anim_delay: 1/30
            anim_reset: True
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 480
'''


class PNGPlayer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        self.delay = root.ids.display_image.anim_delay
        Clock.schedule_once(self.stop_anim, 45*self.delay)  # stop after 45 frames
        return root

    def stop_anim(self, dt):
        print('stopping animation')
        self.root.ids.display_image.anim_delay = -1
        Clock.schedule_once(self.restart_anim, 5)

    def restart_anim(self, dt):
        print('restarting animation')
        self.root.ids.display_image.anim_delay = self.delay

if __name__== '__main__':
    PNGPlayer().run()
```

Comment: Thank you, John! It works, however, I would like to reverse the animation as well, Is that possible?

Comment: As I understand it, the direction of the animation is defined by the order of the files in the `zip`. You could write code to unzip that file and zip the contents in the revere order into another zip file, then use that new zip file to produce animation in the reverse direction.